# Variables are not passed when submitting a form on the same page

Tags: php, html, forms

I have been trying to make it work this for several hours now so I decided to ask for help.

I have a form and when it is submitted it returns on the same page with the values.(this SHOULD happen in thoery) 
i don't get a syntax error but it just doesn't work and the variables are empty.

Take a look at my script here :

http://pastebin.com/FYDmq21b

your help will be MUCH appreciated on this :)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your input elements are outside of the `form` tag, so they are not send a long when you press submit.

On line 223 you have `<form action="test_postback.php" method="post">` and then on line 228 you have the submit button. On line 241 you end the form.

All your input elements however are generated in the table between lines 169 and 201.

So when you press "Submit" you get by the first PHP check `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` because the submit element is in the form. All other checks fail because they have no value:

```
if ($_POST['status']=='1')
{
  //never here, because $_POST['status'] isnt set
}
else if ($_POST['status']=='2')
{
  //never here, because $_POST['status'] isnt set
}
else
{
  //you see this one
  echo 'Invalid status!';
}
```

So the solve it, move `<form action="test_postback.php" method="post">` to line 168 or earlier, to have all input elements inside the `form` tags

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value for the each entry in the table to be equal to itself. I am not sure that this will work but for now this is the only thing i can think of! I hope it will help. I will see your code later more closely and will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have all your input fields outside of the actual form. Move the form action="test_postback.php" method="post">"

up.